# Script for adding an image at the very end of the last paragraph for multiple blocks

Tags: jquery

For each article on a page, I would like to insert an image at the very end of the last paragraph. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="storycontent">
   <p>One</p>
   <p>Two</p>
   <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

There may be several of those sections or only one. There is also an unknown number of `<p></p>` tags.

What I would like to do is insert an `<img />` at the very end of the last `<p>` before the closing tag.

Here is what I have so far, but it is only appending the image tag to the very last `<p>` on the page, and not the last one in the `storycontent` `<div>`

```
jQuery('.storycontent').each(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).last('p').append(img); 
                    //img is a var which contains an Image() element;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing the [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method, which doesn't take any argument and returns the last matched element. You should write something like:

```
jQuery(this).find("p").last().append($(img).clone());
```

Or:

```
jQuery("p", this).last().append($(img).clone());
```

Or even:

```
jQuery("p:last", this).append($(img).clone());
```

Also note that you cannot add the same element to the DOM multiple times, since the element will be moved into its new parent if it's already part of the DOM. A simple solution is to [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it, as the code above does.

Comment: Almost there. This only puts the image in the right place for the last instance of `storyconent`

Comment: @Rob, true, that's because you keep adding the same element to the DOM. I missed that at first, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: So it was moving the Img each iteration?

Comment: @Rob, exactly. This side-effect of the DOM insertion methods is actually used quite often to move elements around.